# Strategy for mapping strings as dates to datetime using Mapster when strings may be empty?

Tags: c#, mapster

I'm using Mapster to map values from a dto based on a json object to a Entity Framework data table.
The destination class has a field 
`[Column(TypeName = "datetime2(3)")]
      public DateTime? CorrectBy { get; set; }` that is being filled from a string representing a date.  The string can be empty or "".

Is there a good mapping strategy for handling this using Mapster?
My mapping currently looks like this:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<InModels.Violation, InspectionViolation>.NewConfig()
            .Map(d=>d.CorrectBy,s=>DateTime.Now,srcCond=>srcCond.CorrectBy=="")
            .Map(d => d.CorrectBy, s =>DateTime.Parse(s.CorrectBy))                
            .IgnoreNullValues(true);
```

but still throws an error saying that it can't convert "" to datetime.

Answer (score 2):

Empty string is not supported converting to `DateTime`. You need to define custom string to datetime mapping.

```
TypeAdapterConfig<string, DateTime?>.NewConfig()
    .MapWith(src => string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(src));
```